# readUTF() causing Android app to hang

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to compile the code at [this](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/01/simple-communication-using.html) link.

The code isn't working because it is getting hung up on this line:

```
textIn.setText(dataInputStream.readUTF());
```

For some reason it doesn't get hung up on `writeUTF()` but it gets hung up on `readUTF()`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Here is my code:

```
public Socket socket = null;
public DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
public DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
public Thread readjsonthrd = new Thread(new ReadJSONThread());

private final static String LOG_TAG = AndroidClient.class.getSimpleName();
private final Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Before OnCreate() Try");
    try {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "In OnCreate() Try");
        socket = new Socket("23.23.175.213", 9000);
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Created Socket");
        dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Created DataOutputStream");
        dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Created DataInputStream");

        Profile p = new Profile();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Created Profile Instance");

        //Gets the local profile via JSON and converts into Profile type
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Created Gson Instance");
        p = gson.fromJson(p.getProfileJSONStr(), Profile.class);
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Converted Profile to JSON");

        //Gson gson = new Gson();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Before: outputJSON = gson.toJson(p);");
        outputJSON = gson.toJson(p);
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Created outputJSON");

        dataOutputStream.writeUTF(outputJSON); //OUTPUT OF JSON FROM LOCAL PROFILE BEING SENT TO THE SERVER
        dataOutputStream.flush();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Created dataOutputStream");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Before initEventHandlers");
    initEventHandlers();
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Create Thread");
    Thread serverthrd = new Thread(new ServerThread());

    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Start Thread");
    serverthrd.start();
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Started Thread");
}

public class ServerThread implements Runnable { 
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Socket socket = null;
    //DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
    //DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Before Server Try Statement");
    try {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "In Server Try Statement");
        //socket = new Socket("23.23.175.213", 1337);

        //dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        //dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        /*Profile p = null;

        //Gets the local profile via JSON and converts into Profile type
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        p = gson.fromJson(p.getProfileJSONStr(), Profile.class);

        //Gson gson = new Gson();
        outputJSON = gson.toJson(p);
        dataOutputStream.writeUTF(outputJSON); //OUTPUT OF JSON FROM LOCAL PROFILE BEING SENT TO THE SERVER
        */
        //dataOutputStream.writeUTF(textOut.getText().toString());  //OUTPUT JSON GOES HERE
        //textIn.setText(dataInputStream.readUTF());


        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Start Thread");
        readjsonthrd.start();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Started Thread");
        /*Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Before inputJSON String");
        inputJSON = dataInputStream.readUTF();

        //Convert 
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "After inputJSON String");
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "InputJSON:" + inputJSON);*/

        //textIn.setText(dataInputStream.readUTF());  //GET JSON COMING FROM SERVER HERE
        refreshViewModels();
    } /*catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/
    finally{
        if (socket != null){
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (dataOutputStream != null){
            try {
                dataOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (dataInputStream != null){
            try {
                dataInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    }
}

public class ReadJSONThread implements Runnable { 
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Socket socket = null;
    //DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
    //DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Before Read JSON Try Statement");
        try {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Before inputJSON String");
            inputJSON = dataInputStream.readUTF();

            //Convert 
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "After inputJSON String");
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you *sending* the data with `writeUTF()`? That's the only API that can produce something that `readUTF()` can understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced somewhat similar issue while integrating with one gov API, I was using readUTF() writeUTF(), and every time stucks at readUTF() without any response.

I found the server is in c and expecting end or request string with **, also response ends with **.

I resolved this, by directly writing on socket's input/output stream, and terminated reading when ** encountered.

```
        Socket client = new Socket(serverIp, port);
        OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
        InputStream in = client.getInputStream();

        String test = "REQUEST-STRING**";
        out.write(test.getBytes());
        out.flush();

        int c;
        while ((c=in.read())!=-1) {
            if (isEndOfResponse(c)) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.print((char)c);
        }
        client.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

`readUTF()` is a blocking network call.  You should call it from a separate `Thread` that isn't the main UI `Thread`, which is how that example does it.  Because it is blocking, it will hang the current `Thread` until is receives data, hence why you should give it a separate one.

The Android docs actually specifically recommend to do this, because you will receive the "Application not responding" error for waiting too long with network calls.

**edit:** Based on the code that you gave, you are just setting up your `Thread` wrong.  You want to create the Socket in the Thread itself (or you can pass it via a constructor).  Having just the `readUTF()` method in the `Thread` won't do much.

My suggestion would be to create some wrapper methods called `write()` and `read()` in the `ReadJSONThread` class and then implement the respective `Socket` methods in there.  Then in your `onCreate()` method you would create your `Thread` object, and when you want to write you can call `<thread>.write()`.  For reading, I would create a loop in the `read()` method and when it successfully reads from the network then have it call a method from your Activity class to perform the processing on the data.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

> readUTF()

if you

> readLine()

you should get rid of your problems (supposing that your server sent a properly terminated line or two as an answer).

NOTE: if you are running this inside your main activity, from ICS onwards you will have problems with restrictions to opening network connections in main thread.  if you opt to not disable restrictions, one fast solution is asynctask, which will probably not allow you to access your main layout (and textview).

Answer (score 0):

`readUTF()` is java specific: first it reads two bytes and uses it as length, then it reads bytes and treats them as modified UTF-8. Basically, for this to work, you need a java server that uses `writeUTF()`.

Also, you should not run long running operations (= network calls) on UI thread. This will prevent UI redraw and event processing, so your app will appear to be "hung". Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to run long-running tasks on a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a thread :

```
  public  static DataInputStream dis;
//...
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                   while (Connected) {
                       String msg = null;
                       try {
                           if(dis==null)break;
                           msg = dis.readLine();
                           Log.i("TAG", "dataRecived: "+msg);
                       } catch (IOException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }

                    }
                    Log.i("TAG", "Reciver END");
                }
            };

            thread.start();
```

So your app wont hang when using readLine or readUTF