# Socket Connection on Java, specify IP

Tags: java, sockets, ip, client-server, client

I'm working on a program where multiple clients need to interact with a remote server.
I've tested it locally and everything's ok (sort of, more on that later), but I can't understand how to set a remote IP.
I read Socket's API and also InetAddress' API. Is this the right way to do it? How does Java deal with IPs? There are not just simple Strings as on the localhost case, am I right?
This is my code:

Client:

```
public class Client {

    final String HOST = "localhost";
    final int PORT = 5000;
    Socket sc;
    DataOutputStream message;
    DataInputStream istream;

    public void initClient() {
        try {
            sc = new Socket(HOST, PORT);
            message = new DataOutputStream(sc.getOutputStream());
            message.writeUTF("test");
            sc.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Server:

```
public class Server {

    final int PORT = 5000;
    ServerSocket sc;
    Socket so;
    DataOutputStream ostream;
    String incomingMessage;

    public void initServer() {
        try {
            sc = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        BufferedReader input;

        while(true){
            try {
                so = new Socket();
                System.out.println("Waiting for clients...");
                so = sc.accept();
                System.out.println("A client has connected.");

                input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(so.getInputStream()));
                ostream = new DataOutputStream(so.getOutputStream());
                System.out.println("Confirming connection...");
                ostream.writeUTF("Successful connection.");

                incomingMessage = input.readLine();
                System.out.println(incomingMessage);
                sc.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I'm dealing with some troubles on my local tests.
First of all, some times I get the following result:

Waiting for clients...
A client has connected.
Confirming connection...
Error: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

Though some other times it works just fine. Well, that first connection at least.

Last question:
When I try to send a message from the server to the client, the program enters in an infite loop and need to be closed manually. I'm adding this to the code to do so:

```
fromServerToClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sc.getInputStream()));  
text = fromServerToClient.readLine();  
System.out.println(text);
```

Am I doing it right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
String host = "localhost";
```

you can use something like

```
String host = "www.ibm.com";
```

or

```
String host = "8.8.8.8";
```

Comment: That works if I have a name representing my IP. Is there anyway to set it simply as numbers, using XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX format?

Comment: @jalbano do you mean like the last example?

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it doesn't work with numbers greater than 127 (byte limit). I mean, it's ok to do it with "127.0.0.1", but I can't replace that number with some friends' IP (like "123.456.789.101"). I think it's wrong to deal with IPs as String, right?

Comment: @jalbano No you can use "254.254.254.254"  The problem is not the address but whether your friend's IP is behind a firewall.  A firewall is specifically designed to block traffic which has not been allowed and most likely, yours has not been allowed.

Comment: So it's not just opening the router port? OK, I'll check that. Thanks.

Comment: @jalbano The PC's firewall needs to allow the port and the router needs to pass the public port to this machine's port.

Answer (score 0):

this is how you would usually implement a Server:

```
class DateServer {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
   ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(5000);
   while (true) {
      Socket incoming = s.accept();
      PrintWriter toClient =
          new PrintWriter(incoming.getOutputStream());
      toClient.println(new Date());
      toClient.flush();
      incoming.close();
   } 
  }
}
```

And following would be As Client:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.net.Socket;
class DateClient {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException
 {
   String host = args[0];
   int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
   Socket server = new Socket(host, port);
   Scanner scan = new Scanner( server.getInputStream() );
   System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
 } 
}
```

Comment: I see you are using a String type variable for the host. But how can I do that if my IP has no name? I think there's something I don't get. I can't just write "123.456.789.101", it doesn't work.

Comment: I just tried that code to send messages from the server to the client. It works, thanks! I'm going to use that from now on.

Comment: I see your confusion. please use my answer for this question as a suggestion : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554220/java-server-socket-response/20554359#20554359..  also if you think my answer helped you, please do not forget to accept it as an answer.

Comment: I found this on your answer. It's the same I'm doing to test my program:  
s = new Socket( "127.0.0.1", port );  
What I don't get is how to make this remote, I mean, the following line is wrong:  
s = new Socket( "123.456.789.101", port );  
How can I set that remote IP to the client?  
I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider doing this in threads. Right now multiple users can't connect to the server at once. This means that they have to queue for connection to the server resulting in very poor performance.

Normally you receive the client and instantiate a new thread to handle the clients request. I only have exampls in C# so i won't bother you with that, but you can easily find examples on google.

eg.
http://www.kieser.net/linux/java_server.html

Comment: I understand I should do this in threads. But I'm not there yet, I want to make it work for just one client first.
My problem is the IP configuration. The link you provided does not bring information about that.